# What Determines SQL Azure Database Edition and Size with EF Code First?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, azure, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

I have a POC solution that uses an ASP.NET MVC 3 to create a web site and Entity Framework 4.3 Code First approach for the data access.  I am able to deploy to a hosted service in Azure and my database gets created in SQL Azure based on my connection string.  What I don't understand is how the database edition (Web) and size (1GB) were determined.  Is this just the default or is it controllable?

I may plan to approach this by setting my database initializer to null when going to production and manage that on my own anyway, but I want to understand the options.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify edition and max size in the `CREATE DATABASE` call. If the edition and maxsize parameters are omitted, the default is Web, 1GB. The full `CREATE DATABASE` call is:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name  [ COLLATE collation_name ]
{
   (<edition_options> [, ...n]) 
}

<edition_options> ::= 
{
   (MAXSIZE = {1 | 5 | 10 | 20 | 30 … 150} GB) 
    |(EDITION = {'web' | 'business'})
}
```

See [this MSDN reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336274.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks.  That's part of the answer.  Maybe my question now boils down to how and if I can control the options used when EF Code First is involved in the database creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one ope the following Common solutions:

### **Option one**: You can change the tier of the Azure Database after it has been created

I hate this solution since (1) you will always forget to do it from time to time. (2) This mean that you must wait more time after the database was created before you start your work. (3) What is the meaning of using ORM if you cannot count on it and you will need to manage the database yourself?!?

### Option two:You can always create the database in advance using direct queries

This is my preferred option for most cases, if you really want to work with ORM like EF. Again the disadvantage is that you manage the database yourself and you need to know to write the queries and not just using the ORM.

You can do this in your application using Entity Framework method "SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery". in fact THIS IS A MUST TO KNOW METHOD.

The way experts can use EF for complex system based on the ability to bypass the ORM bad solutions by writing direct queries ourselves. This means "combine EF with pure queries and database management".

For example:

```
var Query2CreateDB = $"CREATE DATABASE RonenArielyDB2(EDITION = 'Basic', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'Basic',MAXSIZE = 100 MB);";
ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, Query2CreateDB, commandTimeout: 600);
```

And this is why you must first learn how to write queries and manage the database using queries BEFORE you use Entity Framework or any other ORM!

### Option three: Create you own custom EF initializer (override the build-in class)

THIS IS THE BEST SOLUTION FOR DEVELOPERS who want to count on pure ORM solutions like Entity Framework!

There is a great example in the following post!
https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2014/11/12/use-azure-management-api-sdk-in-an-entity-framework-custom-database-initializer/

Choose you solution